# How to use the same input string across multiple chained tasks in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, ide, task

I have multiple tasks that depend on each other and that should all operate on the same folder.

My config looks something like this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "first task",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "bash",
      "args": ["do stuff in ${input:pickFolder}"],
      "dependsOn": "second task"
    },
    {
      "label": "second task",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "bash",
      "args": ["also do stuff in ${input:pickFolder}"]
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "type": "pickString",
      "id": "pickFolder",
      "options": ["path/to/folder", "path/to/other/folder"]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you might imagine I want both tasks run in the same folder. Also, I don`t want to have to pick the folder twice. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) v0.9.

Use the commands:

- `extension.commandvariable.pickStringRemember`
- `extension.commandvariable.rememberPick`